# What is the best index for a "last modified by user" query

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, indexing

I have a Django query like

```
Posts.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-last_modified')
```

What is the best type of index to support this query? I see two options:

1. `Index(fields=['user_id', '-last_modified'])`
2. `Index(fields=['-last_modified'])`

Given that Django automatically indexes foreign keys such as `user_id`, is there any benefit to 1) vs 2)? It seems like 1) would result in fewer items being traversed by the DB, but maybe DBs are "smart enough" to join two separate indexes together and as a result the advantage will be minimal.

My question is theoretical in nature: which index is the better option, in principle?

Comment: #1 would result in exact filtering and ordering.

Comment: The question is why do you need to create an index on "last_modified" column in descending order? Probably, you will list last modification dates on a table, on a board or etc. Yet, while doing that again probably, you need to put some columns like "id, user_id, name, or etc.". Maybe this is a transaction application and users who logged in to the system will need see  their last modification dates. In that case index 1 as "the impaler" said. Otherwise, if you want to see last modification column then index 2. It is just a use case.